# create a default in one Model using values from another Model in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have been struggling over this for days diving down stackoverflow rabbit holes, documentation, and youtube tutorials. I'm just running in circles at this point. So...

I have two models `Variables` and `Entry`. The daily inputs for Entry are to be recordings associated with a given Variable. Ex. I want to track daily sleep as a variable. Then, using that variable, have daily data entry associated with that variable using the Entry model.

My models are below... (I suspect my schema is a mess as well, but it's generally working. This is my first time)

```
class Variables(models.Model):
    ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ('numeric', 'enter a daily number'),
    ('scale', 'rate daily on a scale of 1-10'),
    ('binary', "enter daily, 'yes' or 'no' "),
    ]
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    dep_var = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    dv_reminder = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES, default="numeric")
    # id current user
    evoler = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dep_var

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('entry_new')

class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    evoler = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # id the active user
    dep_variables = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = '')
    data = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

I've tried writing a function that would identify the most recent variable from a given user and to use that as the default value in the `Entry.dep_variables` model. That works in the local environment but causes issues when I try to migrate the database.

Views...

```
def daily_entry(request):
    ''' page to make daily entries '''
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted. GET submitted. Create a blank form
        form = DailyEntryForm()
    else:
        #POST data submitted. Process data
        form = DailyEntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.evoler = request.user
            data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('entry_new'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'entry_new.html', context)
```

Forms...

```
class VariablesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Variables
        fields = ['dep_var', 'dv_reminder' ]
        labels = {'dep_var':'Dependent variable to track', 'dv_reminder': 'Type of measure'}

class DailyEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        var = Variables.dep_var
        fields = ['dep_variables', 'data', 'date']
        labels = {'dep_variables': 'Dependent variable you are tracking',
                    'data': 'Daily entry', 'date': 'Date'}
```

and template.html...

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
  <br>
  <h1>New Entry</h1>
  <form class="" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Save" />

  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Any and all assistance would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: Hello sir, i don't understand, default of what do you want to create? Do you want to save in database or display on the template?

Comment: And the issues are?.. Which of the given code gives you an error and what is it?

Comment: There is no error in the code. I am just looking for a way to have the 'Variables' field 'dep_var' be shown in the webpage generated from the 'Entry model' and 'DailyEntryForm' as the default for 'dep_variables'. 

I want to save the data into a database.